# how to start an factory instance inside a init function of angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-factory

Inside a directive link function i want to invoke a factory instance, Is it possible

.directive('commentList', function(CommentsService, Global) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl:  'xxxx',
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

....I want to invoke a factory from here
            }
}});
.factory('fact'){
}

Answer (score 2):

You can just add fact(factory) at top like this :

```
.directive('commentList', function(CommentsService, Global, fact) { return { restrict: 'E', templateUrl: 'xxxx', link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
```

And then by using fact.callFactMethod() something like this from function.